# Improve speed when parsing numeric data from big files using Python

Tags: python, performance, loops

I'm reading a viewfactor file generated in Ansys (using VFOPT) and converting it into a 2d array in python. I know that the final viewfactor must be a 6982*6982 array.

The viewfactor (file `viewfactor.db`, going from a few MB up to several GB) is formatted as follows:

```
Ansys Release 2020 R2          Build 20.2  Update 20200601  Format     0
RS3D

Number of Enclosures =        1

Enclosure Number =        1 Number of Surfaces =     6982
Element number =    28868 Face Number     2 TOTAL= 1.0000
  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0029 0.0056 0.0000 0.0000 0.0105 0.0000 0.0000
  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
  (numbers numbers numbers)
  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
  0.0000 0.0000

Element number =    28869 Face Number     2 TOTAL= 1.0000
  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0029 0.0056 0.0000 0.0000 0.0105 0.0000 0.0000
  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
  etc etc
```

So, for the 1st element (element 28868) the viewfactor numbers are given (10 at a time, with the final line having possibly less), then there's two lines that I can ignore, then the new numbers are given, and so on.

I'm currently reading the file in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

# the file reading part here is rather quick, it takes a couple seconds
with open('viewfactor.db', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

nfaces = 6982 # I already had this number from before
vf = [[None] * nfaces] * nfaces
row = 0
col = 0

# this is the part that needs optimizing
for line in lines[7:]:
    if line == '': continue
    elif line.startswith('Element number'): # reset counters
        row += 1
        col = 0
    else: # save numbers
        nums = list(map(float, line.split()))
        vf[row][col:col+len(nums)] = nums
        col += len(nums)
vf = np.array(vf)
```

This works, but the script takes forever to execute. I've tested it with a 350MB viewfactor file and it takes about 50 seconds (if needed, I can provide the file).

Is it possible to lower the execution time? Can I do some parallel computing magic? Use C? Do without loops?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Check this out: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html

Comment: can you share a link to that file?

Comment: @dankal444 The Numpy implementation does not seem to be particularly efficient. In fact, it looks like it is a bit slower than `np.array(list(map(float, line.split())))` on my machine on few simple benchmarks... This is pretty sad...

Comment: Such a computation can be significantly made faster using native languages like C or C++ indeed. It can be also parallelized using OpenMP without a huge effort (while this is hard to do that efficiently in Python and the resulting code will likely be significantly slower than the one of a native code). A reasonably optimized sequential C code should already provide a good speed up. Parsing is an expensive process. Consider using binary files if you can.

Comment: @JérômeRichard you are right, sadly. I did numba approach on bytes and multiple lines, seems promising (take a look at the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got something that you can incorporate to your code.
This function below takes any string with numbers (separated by space " " or by new line character, "\n") and converts it to numpy array. Do not feed it with single lines, find all consecutive lines with numbers and give them that.

In my benchamrk, converting 100 lines of 10 numbers was only 6 times slower than doing single line of your `np.array(list(map(float, test_string.split())))`. So speed-up should be at least 10x

Note1: you need to convert those lines to bytes first though, as in the example I provided. Maybe you can optimize and work on the bytes to start with.

Note2: first run of this function will be slow because of compilation, couldn't find right signature for bytes array. Maybe @JeromeRichard can help with that :)
(**EDIT**: added signature and fixes suggested by Jerome in comments)

Note3: you have some more knowledge about this specific file and may find other things to optimize (I guess counting spaces and new lines is not necessary, and you could provide it into function as an input).

```
@nb.jit('(Bytes(uint8, 1, "C"),)', nopython=True)
def numba_str_multiline(txt):
    # zero digit code = 48
    # space code = 32
    # new line code = 10
    # dot code = 46
    n_spaces_and_new_lines = 0
    for i in range(len(txt)):
        char = txt[i]
        if char == 32 or char == 10:
            n_spaces_and_new_lines += 1
    result = np.zeros(n_spaces_and_new_lines)

    current_number = 0.0
    idx_of_current_number = 0
    before_dot = True
    divisor = 10
    for i in range(len(txt)):
        char = txt[i]
        if char == 32 or char == 10:
            result[idx_of_current_number] = current_number
            idx_of_current_number += 1
            divisor = 10
            current_number = 0.0
            before_dot = True  # for cases if there is no dot at all
        elif char == 46:
            before_dot = False
        else:
            if before_dot:
                current_number = current_number * 10.0 + (char - 48)
            else:
                current_number += (char - 48) / divisor
                divisor *= 10

    return result


test_string = "1.2345 678.123400 0.0000 0.0029 0.0056 0.0000 0.0000 0.0105 0.0000 0.0000"
test_string_multiline = """1.2345 678.123400 0.0000 0.0029 0.0056 0.0000 0.0000 0.0105 0.0000 0.0000
""" * 100
test_bytes_multiline = bytes(test_string_multiline, 'utf-8')
result = numba_str_multiline(test_bytes_multiline)
```

Comment: You can use the signature `@nb.njit('(Bytes(uint8, 1, "C"),)')` for this code to be compiled eagerly ;) . Note Numba is very inefficient for string, and not great (but fine) for bytes. The Numba code is faster than the naive Python approach but it is still inefficient compared to what could be done in C (certainly several times faster with an optimized code, especially if the numbers have a fixed size). On my machine, a significant time seems to be spent iterating on `txt` and allocating `result`.

Comment: You can use `for i in range(len(txt)): char = txt[i]` for faster performance and `(char - 48)` rather than `(char - 48.0)`. This is 25-30% faster on my machine. The key for performance is to use SIMD instruction here but this is not really possible in Numba (at least it is not easy nor results in a simple code). For example, AVX can compute 32 characters in a row. Most x86 CPUs can execute 2~3 basic integer AVX instructions per cycle. For double precision, AVX can compute 4 numbers per instruction (and often 2 per cycle too). This is generally enough to compute files at the speed of >1 GiB/s.

Comment: Anyway, this is 15-20x faster than the naive Python implementation on my machine once optimized and might be enough for the OP.

Comment: Hello @dankal444, thanks for the reply! I'm sorry if I haven't tested the code yet, but I'm away for the Easter holidays and I don't have time to get to my pc, but I'll try the script as soon as I can. I have the option to export directly the view factor file in binary form, I'll see if that helps in improving the speed further. Thanks again!

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you for signature and those fixes! I got similar improvement on my machine. Apart from that, I tried to converting to uint8 but that gave no improvement at all. Seems bytes give the same performance as uint8 numpy array (which is good I think?).

Comment: @man-teiv Happy Easter man :) take your time

Comment: I've tested the function, and it works great! Reading time was reduced from 50s to 2.5s, so there was about a 20x performance improvement :)
I only have a doubt: I want to skip the first loop to determine `n_spaces_and_new_lines` since I already know this number. But I've tried changing the function from `def numba_str_multiline(txt):` to `def numba_str_multiline(txt, num):` in order to build directly the array as `result = np.zeros(num)` but the following error message appears: `TypeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: fix up args)`. Is it possible to pass more than one arg?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to pass any (sane) number of arguments, you just need to fix signature. `@nb.jit('(Bytes(uint8, 1, "C"), int64)', nopython=True)`

Comment: That was it! Thanks again for your patience and your super helpful solution